# How do I copy a bitfield from code memory to internal memory?

Tags: assembly, 8051

My purpose is to copy the bitfield with the followig inputs:

```
;   R5 - Base address of the bitfield in code memory (high byte)
;   R6 - Base address of the bitfield in code memory (low byte)
;   R7 - Base address of the bitfield in the internal memory
```

And I have the following bitfield data:

```
BITFIELD_LEN  EQU 16
BITFIELD_ADDR_IRAM  EQU 0x40
BITFIELD_ADDR_CODE:
DB 0x42, 0x1A,  0x7F, 0x80,  0x55, 0xAA,  0xA0, 0xCC,  0x12, 0x13,  0x11, 0x10,  0x05, 0xAA,  0x42, 0x34
; Pattern in binary format:
; 0100 0010 0001 1010 0111 1111 1000 0000 0101 0101 1010 1010 1010 0000 1100 1100
; 0001 0010 0001 0011 0001 0001 0001 0000 0000 0101 1010 1010 0100 0010 0011 0100
```

```
CODE2IRAM:
    org 0x0070
    mov DPTR, R5
    mov DPTR, R6
    mov R4, #06     ;count
    back: movc a, @a+dptr
        mov @R7, a
        inc dptr
        inc R7
        clr a
        djnz R4, back
    org 0x40
    DB 0x42, 0x1A,  0x7F, 0x80,  0x55, 0xAA,  0xA0, 0xCC,  0x12, 0x13,  0x11, 0x10,  0x05, 0xAA,  0x42, 0x34 
    end
```

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: Looks like 8051 ?

Comment: `mov DPTR, R5/R6` should not assemble. You should use `mov DPL, R6; MOV DPH, R5`. I would put the `clr a` just before the `movc`, but otherwise that makes sense. What problem do you have?

Answer (score 2):

There are some small issues with your code, but in principle it is the right approach:

- You cannot load 8-bit parts to `DPTR` by using the same destination twice. The two bytes of `DPTR` can be reached separately via the predefined direct addresses `DPH` (`DPTR` high byte) and `DPL` (`DPTR` low byte). You might need to include a register include file for this.
- The count is 16, not 6.
- Clear the accumulator `A` where you need it, in this case before the `movc` instruction.
- Since this seems to be a subroutine, a `ret` is missing after the loop.
- I inserted some empty lines for better readability.

```
CODE2IRAM:
    org 0x0070

    mov DPH, R5
    mov DPL, R6
    mov R4, #16     ;count

back:
    clr a
    movc a, @a+dptr
    mov @R7, a
    inc dptr
    inc R7
    djnz R4, back

    ret

    org 0x0040

    DB 0x42, 0x1A,  0x7F, 0x80,  0x55, 0xAA,  0xA0, 0xCC,  0x12, 0x13,  0x11, 0x10,  0x05, 0xAA,  0x42, 0x34 

    end
```

Comment: _"You don't need to clear the accumulator"_ you do since `movc a, @a+dptr` will use the current value for indexing.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, i stand corrected. ;-) Sometimes we need some minute of thought more.